# How to redirect/forward between a tun/tap device and a socket using linux tools?

Tags: networking, tcp, socks, tunneling

I have a socks5 proxy that is bind to eth0. It opens two ports, Port1 is used to connect to remote (for example a http server), Port2 is to listen for clients to connect.

Then I created a tun device. And set routing table to make all data go through the tun device.

Now is my question, how to link the tun device and Port2? So all data will actually go through the socks5 proxy?

I have found tun2socks that could do this. But still, I am wondering if there is other ways like using iptables to archive that.

Comment: It seems like you should bind the socks5 proxy listener to the tun interface, and then configure clients to use the socks proxy @ the IP of tun interface

Comment: If the socks5 proxy listens on the tun, then a "global proxy" should be set. Thus all data flow go through the proxy. But the reason I use a tun here is that so I could use a route table to control which dest should be through the proxy, which should not.